# How to include emoticons in chatserver

Tags: java

Can someone help me how can I include emoticons in this code.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
/**
* A simple Swing-based client for the chat server. Graphically
* it is a frame with a text field for entering messages and a
* textarea to see the whole dialog.
*
* The client follows the Chat Protocol which is as follows.
* When the server sends "SUBMITNAME" the client replies with the
* desired screen name. The server will keep sending "SUBMITNAME"
* requests as long as the client submits screen names that are
* already in use. When the server sends a line beginning
* with "NAMEACCEPTED" the client is now allowed to start
* sending the server arbitrary strings to be broadcast to all
* chatters connected to the server. When the server sends a
* line beginning with "MESSAGE " then all characters following
* this string should be displayed in its message area.
*/

public class ChatClient {

BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chatter");
JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);

JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);

/**

* Constructs the client by laying out the GUI and registering a
* listener with the textfield so that pressing Return in the
* listener sends the textfield contents to the server. Note
* however that the textfield is initially NOT editable, and
* only becomes editable AFTER the client receives the NAMEACCEPTED
* message from the server.
*/

public ChatClient() {

// Layout GUI
textField.setEditable(false);

messageArea.setEditable(false);
frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "North");
frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
frame.pack();

// Add Listeners
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

/**
* Responds to pressing the enter key in the textfield by sending
* the contents of the text field to the server. Then clear
* the text area in preparation for the next message.
*/

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  out.println(textField.getText());
  textField.setText("");
}

});

}

/**
* Prompt for and return the address of the server.
*/
private String getServerAddress() {
  return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    frame,
    "Enter IP Address of the Server:",
    "Welcome to the Chatter",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}

/**
* Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
*/
private String getName() {
  return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    frame,
    "Choose a screen name:",
    "Screen name selection",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

/**
* Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
*/
private void run() throws IOException {
  // Make connection and initialize streams
  String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
  Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
  socket.getInputStream()));
  out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
  // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
  while (true) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
      out.println(getName());
    } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
      textField.setEditable(true);
    } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
      messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
    }
  }
}

/**
* Runs the client as an application with a closeable frame.
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
  client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  client.frame.setVisible(true);
  client.run();
}
}
```

Comment: What is this mate? What have you tried and please don't post full code/ First check how code is working try something yourself and then post the question on which part you are having difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I didn't look your code to be honest (sry about that), but what you are asking is something very simple. Have you noticed that all emoticons have a sequence of characters?

Skype Example: :* :) (y) ... and so on

When compiling the message, a simple replaceAll takes place.

```
String message = "Of course :)";
// in this place here you will make a loop for all your emoticons or just 
// match it by regex.
message = message.replaceAll(":)", imageToAdd);

sendMessage(message);
```

That is basically what happens in the chat when you add an emoticon. You can use a HashMap to, where the id would be the char sequence and the value would be the path or image component of that emoticon. (It is much faster if you have several)

Comment: what is "imageToAdd" ?

Comment: that would be the Image that will take place instead of the character sequence. If you were doing it in web it would be a <img /> tag for example.

Comment: Is this the correct way to replace, 
str=str.replaceAll(":)",smiliesgeneral3_640x480.jpgs);
just add image name???

Answer (score 0):

Didnt bashed my head in your code but what i have used in my chatbox is this:

> Autoreplace smiles text with appropriate images in JEditorPane.

To support the autoreplacing we need a JEditorPane with StyledEditorKit (or extension class) to provide images in text. We just add a DocumentListener to process text insert events. After inserting we check whether the changed text contains smiles string - the ":)". If it contains we replace the smile text with an appropriate image.

The example provides only one smile support - the ":)" string but can be easy extended.

NOTE: We should surround our code with SwingUtilities.invokeLater() because we cannot change document during mutation intercepted in the listener.

[image]

```
The example code is below:

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;

public class AutoreplaceSmiles extends JEditorPane {
    static ImageIcon SMILE_IMG=createImage();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Autoreplace :) with Smiles images example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final AutoreplaceSmiles app = new AutoreplaceSmiles();
        app.setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit());
        app.initListener();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(app);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);

        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public AutoreplaceSmiles() {
        super();
    }

    private void initListener() {
        getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
                final DocumentEvent e=event;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (e.getDocument() instanceof StyledDocument) {
                            try {
                                StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument)e.getDocument();
                                int start= Utilities.getRowStart(AutoreplaceSmiles.this,Math.max(0,e.getOffset()-1));
                                int end=Utilities.getWordStart(AutoreplaceSmiles.this,e.getOffset()+e.getLength());
                                String text=doc.getText(start, end-start);

                                int i=text.indexOf(":)");
                                while(i>=0) {
                                    final SimpleAttributeSet attrs=new SimpleAttributeSet(
                                       doc.getCharacterElement(start+i).getAttributes());
                                    if (StyleConstants.getIcon(attrs)==null) {
                                        StyleConstants.setIcon(attrs, SMILE_IMG);
                                        doc.remove(start+i, 2);
                                        doc.insertString(start+i,":)", attrs);
                                    }
                                    i=text.indexOf(":)", i+2);
                                }
                            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    static ImageIcon createImage() {
        BufferedImage res=new BufferedImage(17, 17, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g=res.getGraphics();
        ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(0,0,16,16);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(0,0,16,16);

        g.drawLine(4,5, 6,5);
        g.drawLine(4,6, 6,6);

        g.drawLine(11,5, 9,5);
        g.drawLine(11,6, 9,6);

        g.drawLine(4,10, 8,12);
        g.drawLine(8,12, 12,10);
        g.dispose();

        return new ImageIcon(res);
    }
}
```